# Manually install WFS-T plugin to implement with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, wfs-t

I'd like to use this [Flexberry WFS-T Leaflet plugin](https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST), and am required to manually install it.

I've put it in my assets folder in this way:

[image]

Imported leaflet and three js files:

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/src/WFS.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/src/WFST.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/src/GML.js"></script>
```

Initialized this way:

```
var rooturl = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ged/ows';

var wfst = new L.WFST({
            url: rooturl,
            typeNS: 'ged',
            typeName: 'GED_IDV',
            crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
            geometryField: 'geom',
            style: {
              color: 'blue',
              weight: 2
            }
          });
```

But, something isn't working, and I suspect the installation, but can't find anything in the docs.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GML' of undefined    
    at initialize (WFS.js:43)    
    at initialize (WFST.js:7)    
    at new i (Class.js:22)    
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):590)    
    at e (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)    
    at t (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: ...and when/how are you loading the main Leaflet JS file?

Comment: @IvanSanchez updated my question. I import leaflet first amongst several other modules. the wfs-t js files are imported last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the build version "leaflet-wfst.src.min.js" (I call it from CDN here but you can download it locally. As stated in comment, you must load Leaflet before this script as it requires `L` namespace (created by Leaflet) to work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
  crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
  crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-wfst@2.0.1-beta.25/dist/leaflet-wfst.src.min.js"></script>
```

You can also build the same file with

```
git clone https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST.git
cd Leaflet-WFST/
npm i
npm install -g grunt-cli
grunt
```

It will throw an error due to Leaflet not available when testing with Phantomjs but you will find the generated file in `dist` directory